# Проблема с Post запросом

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

Есть такой vue метод:

```
methods: {

sendTrackerClientData () {

    return axios.post("https://seo-gmbh.eu/couriertracker/json/couriertracker_api.php?action=tracking.data_save&key_id=00227220201402050613" , {
      tracking_data: 'some data'
     })
    .then(response => {
      console.log('post method is working!');
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
},
```

}

Который навешивается на событие нажатия кнопки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После попытки отправить данные - в фаербаге можем увидеть вышеописанные предупреждения и ошибку.
Попытка добавить заголовки по типу:

```
return axios.post("https://seo-gmbh.eu/couriertracker/json/couriertracker_api.php?action=tracking.data_save&key_id="+ this.$store.state.tracker.trackingKeyId , {
   headers: {
       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Powered-By': 'bacon'
      },
      tracking_data: this.$store.state.tracker.trackingClientData
     })
    .then(response => {
      console.log('post method is working!');
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Ни к чему не привела.
Вопрос:
Что я упустил из виду и каким образом можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Могу только предположить "http"  и  "http**s**", надо попробовать на `http://seo...` отправить.  А это только сервер может установить - `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Comment: http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2020/02/06/0023/2790/1571558/58/44348e7020.jpg
А если Get запрос работает нормально на клиенте - причина возможна на стороне сервера в таком случае? Можите уточнить что вы имели ввиду под ""http" и "https", надо попробовать"?

Comment: На картинке не видно какой протокол у `localhost`, вероятно это `http`. А запрос на `https` - скорее всего, что-то и блокируется. Вот здесь можно почитать [Same-origin_policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). И кстати сейчас попробовал отправить на этот адрес через [POST](https://yadi.sk/i/3ulastBmmY7Y-Q), с помощью программки `Fiddler 4` - работает так-же как и GET.

Comment: Дело в том что я с помощью jquery тоже отправлял Post запрос:
подключая его в этот же vue компонент:
http://joxi.ru/D2PgJPYhkaJEWm
И все работает нормально.
Как понять чего конкретно в axios не хватает для корректной работы в данном случае?
Какие есть варианты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Если это плагины**, может возникнуть [такая проблема](https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/issues/97#issuecomment-363850306)(оставлю на всякий случай).

**Если напрямую импортируем Axios** `import axios from 'axios'`.

1. Пробуем отправить **GET** и смотрим его заголовки:

```js
// Заголовки запроса GET
:authority: seo-gmbh.eu
:method: GET
:path: /couriertracker/json/couriertracker_api.php?action=tracking.data_save&key_id=00227220201402050613
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
cache-control: no-cache
origin: http://localhost:8080
pragma: no-cache
referer: http://localhost:8080/
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36
```

2. Пробуем отправить **POST**, после котой возникает ошибка

```
Предварительные заголовки POST
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36
```

Читаем последнее предложение ошибки(ЭТО СHROME, у вас этой ОШИБКИ НЕ ВИДНО)

```
Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response
```

Axios по дефолту установил `Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8`, а сервер не хочет принимать этот тип данных или просто не настроен.

Изменить заголовки по дефолту можно и самому, но это потребует и самостоятельно обрабатывать тело запроса.
Оставлю это здесь [config-defaults](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#config-defaults)

3. Вероятнее всего, сервер принимает обычную форму **FormData**.

```js
form = new FormData()
form.append(key , value)
```

Пробуем отправить **POST** с формой:

Axios выдал правильный заголок `content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7H24tt13aCEzW6SQ`

```js
// Заголовки POST
:authority: seo-gmbh.eu
:method: POST
:path: /couriertracker/json/couriertracker_api.php?action=tracking.data_save&key_id=00227220201402050613
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 153
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7H24tt13aCEzW6SQ
origin: http://localhost:8080
pragma: no-cache
referer: http://localhost:8080/
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36

// Тело запроса Form Data
tracking_data: some_data
```

... и мы получили нормальный ответ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Пример тестового компонента

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button v-on:click="clickAx">click</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
// Тело запроса
const body = { tracking_data: 'some_data' /* , ...  */ }
const form = new FormData()
// Если много ключей сразу все и запихиваем
Object.entries(body).forEach(([key, value]) => form.append(key, value))

export default {
  methods: {
    clickAx: function() {
      return axios
        .post(
          'https://seo-gmbh.eu/couriertracker/json/couriertracker_api.php?action=tracking.data_save&key_id=00227220201402050613',
          // наши доп-параметры
          form
        )
        .then((response) => {/*...*/})
        .catch(function(error) {/*...*/})
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Такой вопрос:
Если мы исходим что невозможно отправить пост запрос(с помощью Axios) - тогда как бы вы поступили на моем месте?
(если бы разрабатывали проект на нуксте)
Какие есть альтернативы в плане решений связанных с этим видом запроса?

Comment: @MikeKharkov Вы меня не правильно поняли. Имелось ввиду, что установленный параметр неверно обрабатывается `axios`. Разумеется отправить тело запроса можно, иначе зачем там `post`. И я тоже хорош, от недосыпа не заметил, что у вас запрос не через плагин Vue `this.axios`, а напрямую. Да еще и ошибки которые у меня возникали в хроме, я воспринимал как и ваши на картинке, не дочитав самый конец(последнее предложение). Оказалось ошибка возникает из-за двух факторов: неверный тип параметра установил неверный заголовок, а сервер не захотел этого принять. Обновил ответ, надеюсь поможет.